# image with Boolean value on Onclick in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I am just wondering if there is a way to pass a *boolean* value (true and false) to an image.
What I am trying to do here is to make an image as a sort of `switch`. When I press the image it will return the value true and when I press it again it will return the value value so on and so fort.

More like the image will act as a `ToggleButton` or a `Checkbox` when ever the user click it will return true then when it is clicked again the value will be false. When the value is true the image will start my service project and when the user clicks the image again it will stop the service.

Comment: Are You talking about http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html ?

Comment: You could just maintain a counter and achieve that ! onClick increment the count by 1 , if the number is odd then return true if even then set false !

Comment: wow thanks adnan il try that one didnt really think about that thank you

Comment: You may use tag property of view to achieve such kind of behavior..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every view has its "setTag()" method. You can use it by following way.

```
//say 1 is for true
view.setTag(1);

//say 0 is for false
view.setTag(0);
```

To retrieve value,

```
int flag = (Integer) view.getTag();
if(flag==1)
//true condition
else
//false condition
```

**Edit**

If you have set id in tag, following will be your code to retrieve that id.

```
view.setTag(view.getId());
//...
int id = (Integer) view.getTag();
```

**Code**

```
scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int flag = (Integer)view.getTag();
        if(flag==1){
            //change to 0 here
            view.setTag(0);
            //rest of code
        }else
        {
            //change to 1 here
            view.setTag(1);
            //rest of code
        }
}
```

Comment: give me time to try your answer thank you should i change view in view.settag1 with the image id?

Comment: so i need to change view in view.setTag(1) with my image ID?im i tried this one but i get error in int flag - view.getTag() part.

Comment: i was able to run it but im having problem its only returns the false value so he keeps to returning null but when i change it to 0 its keeps returning true value it does not go to else part :)) but this one is really great help thank you

Comment: how do i set 1 as true and 0 as false?

Comment: its just our understanding as shown in code. I got from C++ code structure. 1 means true and 0 means false. When you get 1, consider it as true otherwise false.

Comment: no i mean when i click it already that means its value is now 1 so when i click it again the value should be 0 now since its current value is 1.after if i need to tell the code that its current value is 1 right?how do i do that?:))

Comment: @SatineKainne, i edited code in answer. Is that what do you want?

Comment: i tried but i got error on this line int flag = (Integer) v.getTag(); this my code can you take a look?
public void switch(View v){
  @SuppressWarnings("unused")
  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second.class);
  int flag = (Integer) v.getTag();
  String message = null;
  if(flag==1){
  message = "ON";
  startService(new Intent(this, Second.class));
  v.setTag(0);
  }else{
  
  message = "Off";
  stopService(new Intent(this, Second.class));
  v.setTag(1);
  }
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }

Comment: @SatineKainne, I test your code, have you defined "button.setTag(1);" after declaring button? There should be some default value set before it can get. I think that is your error.

Comment: you mean button.setTag(1) does it work on imageview im using imageview ?il try it out i just need its findViewById(R.id.img)?i put img.setTag(1)?

Comment: Ya.. I mean view whichever button, image, textview anything. I tried your code for button. And every time I click on it, it display first "on", "off", "on" sequence in toast.

Comment: int img = (Integer) v.getTag(); this is how i did it this is my error

Comment: public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity);
  scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
  scanButton.setTag(1);
  scanButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {   public void onClick(View v) {
    doswitch(v);
   }
  });
 }
 public void doswitch(View v) {
  int flag = (Integer) v.getTag();
  String message = null;
  if (flag == 1) {
   message = "ON";
   v.setTag(0);
  } else {
   message = "Off";
   v.setTag(1);
  }
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

Comment: il follow your code :)) its working thank you so much watch i might as another question

Answer (score 0):

```
   public static int Count=0;
 Myimageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(Count==0)
            {
             //Toggle On
             //Start Service;
           Count=1;
             }
          else
            {
            //Toggle Off
            //Stop Service
             Count=0;
            }
    }
});
```

Comment: U can also use switch case instead of if-else in On click event.

Comment: how i can i make to switch?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `flag`

something like this

```
boolean flag = false;
```

inside `onClick` Method

```
flag = !flag;
```

and check if the `flag` is `true` then start `service` otherwise `stop` the `service`.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to create a new class.  Derive it from ImageView, and use a flag that gets toggled whenever you receive a TOUCH_UP motion event in onTouchEvent.  Then you can override whatever other behavior your want to based on the value of that flag.

Answer (score 0):

One other option would be to extend the ImageView class have your own attributes within it and in your OnCLickListener access the required attributes.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // cast to the custom class
            CustomImageView customImageView=(CustomgImageView)v;
            //access the attributes and perform the required action. 

        }
    });
```